# Are "is this a legitimate phenomenon?" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I bumped into an implausible-sounding story from a reputable news source (the BBC, in this case), but for which I can find no supporting evidence (e.g., a Wikipedia article). Would it be on-topic to ask if this phenomenon has been confirmed to really happen or has been debunked?

The FAQ mentions the New York Times as an example of a claim being notable. If this *is* an appropriate topic, should we have a "tabloid" tag for this kind of "is this real phenomenon?" question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the claim is specific and notable, then bring it on.

If it's such a vague claim that no one can possibly address it meaningfully, then it's probably better to spend some time researching what is actually claimed before asking.

Also, the claim needs to be notable, if the BBC claimed that there's a pink unicorn orbiting the planet, I guess people would not believe it and think of a prank, thus making the claim non-notable (because no-one actually believes it).

Finally, keep in mind that we can't allow questions about current events -- when they are clearly unsubstantiated and single-source, there's really no way to investigate them.